# Converting Time to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, decimal, type-conversion

All i have to do that just find the overtime of  employee. The attendance sheet comes in CSV file and I've already saved the data to a table. The data  Field hours is 12:10:00.0000000, and The Working Hour per day is 11:00:00.0000000. I've calculated the difference between these two times using Timespan.

```
   DateTime date, hours, working_hours ;
   TimeSpan ot_hours = TimeSpan.Zero;
   TimeSpan tot_hours = TimeSpan.Zero;
   if (hours > working_hours)
    {
       ot_hours = (hours - working_hours);
     }
```

This code has set in a loop. after completing the loop I need to stote the total overtime into another variable. so wrote

```
 tot_hours += tot_hours + ot_hours;
```

And next I need to find the salary overtime amount for the employee. 
I've tried to convert this tot_hours(TimeSpan ) into Decimal. But it didn't work.

```
   tothrsvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(tot_hours);
   totalvalue = rate * tothrsvalue;
```

Anyone here.. Please have a look and help me.. Thanks in advance.

the total calculation part is given below:

```
         decimal basics = Convert.ToDecimal(dtamt.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString());
                            decimal rate = 0;
                            rate = ((basics / 30) / 8);
                            txtrate.Text = rate.ToString("0.000");

                            tothrsvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(total);
                            totalvalue = rate * tothrsvalue;
                            txtamount.Text = totalvalue.ToString("0.000");
                            amt = Convert.ToDecimal(txtamount.Text);
```

Comment: I expect `tot_hours += tot_hours + ot_hours;` is wrong, as this basically means double the total and then add the overtime. In cases where total is `0` then you won't notice this being a problem, but in other cases it will cause incorrect results. You should just use `tot_hours += ot_hours;` or `tot_hours = tot_hours + ot_hours;`

Comment: yeah.. thank you @musefan .. That was my mistake. i've already corrected that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing `TimeSpan` to `decimal` does not too much sense because time is not a numeric value *at all*.

But you can use it's [`TotalHours` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours) which returns `double`.

```
var total = tot_hours.TotalHours;
```

Comment: I've tried that too..  total =  tot_hours.TotalHours;

Comment: Ok. the type of other variables is decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Y need to to convert a TimeSpan to a decimal ? Its cannot be done becuase it isn't numeric.

You probably want `tot_hours.TotalHours`, which is a double that includes the fractional portion.

or `tot_hours.TotalHours.ToString("#.00");`

Answer (score 0):

ot_hours is now a **Timestamps difference = Seconds !** Divide them by 60 to make minutes

example : total = 2 minutes = 120 seconds etc.)